# Find out CSS element rotation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

Is there a safe way to find out CSS rotation and screen position for an HTML element? Could I use `element.getBoundingClientRect()` and `window.getComputedStyle(element).transform`?

*UPDATE*
Still looking for a solution. The solution discussed in the comment does not work for inner elements when the parent element is rotated. (I can walk the DOM up to BODY, of course, but it seems like overkill.)

Comment: You could use the `window.getComputedStyle` but it's not that easy to extract rotation from it (because the browser converts the rotation into a matrix). See http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/ for an implementation. As soon as you got the rotation you may calculate all the other bounds /edges of your object using simple math. The boundingClientRect does not help at all as it's not rotated.

Comment: Ah, fine, @jbrosi. Then I do not have to do the math. ;-) So everyone assumes that using the returned matrix is ok?

Comment: yep, never heared something different. At least if your matrix was created only by using rotate. If the matrix combines multiple translates, scalings and rotations the math to extract the values could be mind-blowing (at least for me).

Comment: Oh, yes it will combine all of those (but be 2D in my current case). But... are you also saying that `getBoundingClientRect` is no longer reliable (since we now have CSS rotation)?

Comment: It's perfectly fine for returning the "bounding rect" meaning a rect where your rotated/scaled/transformed object fits into. But you can't read the rotation from it as it's a non-rotated rect.

Comment: Good, then everything turns out to be rather simple!

Comment: Oh, though it did not work for inner elements. :-(  -- `getBoundingClientRect` still works correctly, but `getComputedStyle` returns "none" for inner element even when a parent element is rotated. (At least when looking at SVG sub elements.)

Comment: As you could rotate the inner element too, it would make no sense to show the same rotation as the parent element :(. If the parent is rotated by 45 and the inner element by 45, too it would result in a 90 degrees rotation for the inner element if you compare it to the body.

Comment: Yes, it is a bit complicated. However both I and the browser need the same information. The browser has it (for display), but does not seem to care about giving me the info. Or, is there something like "getComputedTransform"?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't... I guess you would have to crawl through all the parents, check if they have a transform, multiply them from top to bottom and you receive your calculated one (I'm not really sure how left/top translations via plain css and transform-origin settings would get involved here - I guess you have to add the transforms for them, too :/). Going that far it might just be easier to use canvas and do all the math yourself...

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but I am sure the browser caches the information somewhere so I hoped there was a way to get it. Maybe I am just asking this question a bit too early, the function exposing the computed transform might be on its way to us?

Comment: Maybe I should just keep track of this in my code now. And send a note to Chrome and Firefox developers.

Comment: Found this interesting approach - maybe it could help you: http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/calculating-element-vertex-data-from-css-transforms/

Comment: Very good guide: https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/